# Docker Beginner Tutorial のVolumesの説明が分かりません

Tags: docker

```
version: "3"
services:
  es:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.2
    container_name: es
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
  web:
    image: prakhar1989/foodtrucks-web
    command: python app.py
    depends_on:
      - es
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    volumes:
      - ./flask-app:/opt/flask-app
volumes:
    esdata1:
      driver: local
```

上記のコードはここにあります：[チュートリアル](https://docker-curriculum.com/)

VolumesはContainerが終わってもPersistするデータの事だと思いますが、既にここ：

```
volumes:
          - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

とここ：

```
volumes:
          - ./flask-app:/opt/flask-app
```

で各Container内にMount pointを指定していると思います。
なので最後の部分が何を指定しているのかが分かりません：

```
volumes:
        esdata1:
          driver: local
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

最後の部分ではPersistent volume(esdata1)の設定をしています。
ローカルのディレクトリをマウントする(flask-appディレクトリ)ならばこれはいりませんが、Persistent volumeを使う場合はこのように別途利用するVolumeを宣言する必要があります。

Comment: こちらも見ましたが：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39175194/docker-compose-persistent-data-mysql

Comment: 最後のPersistent VolumeはHost Machineにセーブされて、`es`と`web`各自の`volumes`はコンテナ内にマウントされる事ですか。

Comment: その理解で良いと思います。コメントの回答にもあるようにPersistent Volumeを利用するとDockerによって定められたディレクトリ(/var/lib/docker/volumes)以下にディレクトリが作られ、そのディレクトリをコンテナでマウントできるようになります。このボリュームはコンテナ内で実行されるプロセス(例えばElasticSearchやMySQL)で永続化したいデータの保存場所などに利用されます。一方flask-appのほうは開発者が作成した`app.py`があるディレクトリをコンテナにマウントします。こうすることによってローカルマシンで`app.py`を編集するとコンテナ内のプログラムも書き換えることができます。

Comment: ちなみに作成したPersistent Volumeは`docker volume ls`で確認できます